# How can I filter an array of type [[String:String]] using UISearchBar and display as String

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have parsed a JSON array which gives me `[[String:String]]` which I then put into a table view.

I want to use a `UISearchBar` to be able to search the data, but am having trouble because I'm not sure how to deal with the `[[String:String]]` format.

I have tried creating another variable which holds the array data as `[String]` and I can filter it, but I can't display the results correctly.  Sorry if this is a bit confusing as i have confused myself the last couple of hours trying to figure it out. Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class StartViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var names = [
        [String: String]
        ]()

    var isSearching = false
    var filteredData = [String]()


    @IBOutlet weak
    var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak
    var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",
                                                 for: indexPath)
        let name = names[indexPath.row]
        let text: String!

        // here I get 'Cannot assign value of type '[String : String]' to type 'String?''
        if isSearching {
            text = filteredData[indexPath.row]

        } else {
            text = nil
        }

        cell.textLabel ? .text = name["name"]
        cell.textLabel ? .textColor = UIColor.blue

        return cell
    }
}
```

**Here are two sections**

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

        isSearching = false

        view.endEditing(true)

        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        isSearching = true

        // and here I get 'Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String : String]' and 'String?''
        filteredData = names.filter({
            $0 == searchBar.text
        })

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

edit:
// here is my parsing function if that helps at all

```
func parse(json: JSON) {
    for result in json[].arrayValue {
        let name = result["name"].stringValue
        let obj = ["name": name]

        names.append(obj)

    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to display both full and filtered data both arrays must be of the same type.

```
var filteredData = [[String:String]]()
```

In `cellForRow` use the array depending on `isSearching`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",
                                             for: indexPath)

    let text : [String:String]
    if isSearching {
        text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        text = names[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = text["name"]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue

    return cell
}
```

In `searchBar:searchDidChange` you have to filter by a key for example

```
filteredData = names.filter({
     $0["name"] == searchBar.text
})
```

However I recommend to use a custom class or struct rather than a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've done your corrections, it has successfully got rid of the errors, but for some reason when I search, only the first name in the array is ever shown in the table view. I know that it IS filtering because it will only show anything is I type in one of the names that actually exists, anything else returns nothing, but I have no idea where to look now.

Comment: You are searching for a full name (`==`) rather than `hasPrefix` or `contains`

Comment: also for more clarification when i say the first name, the list is a list of names of cryptocurrencys, and no matter which one i type it always returns 'bitcoin', do you have any insight on a better method to collect and search this data?